# Getting Object details from list

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist

I am working in a **win form** where there is a list named Notes which contains different values like **NoteId**, **Notetype**, **NoteName**. Each created note is shown in a **Panel** with noteid, note type,notename .Like that all the panel is loaded in the form.

The requirement is when ever user clicks on any of the field i.e. NoteId or NoteType or NoteName, all the details should be loaded in editable text-boxes for editing.

When User clicks on NoteId which is Unique I do the following to get the Note Details:

```
foreach (Note n in noteRetrieve)
{
     Var index = Array.FindIndex(noteRetrieve, x => x.noteType == clickValue);            
}
```

So I get the index of that particular Note and with that I get the notedetails

```
tbTitle.Text = noteRetrieve[index].noteName;
```

& so on.

But **NoteType** and **NoteName** is **NOT UNIQUE**, So I can't use above logic.

How to do this ?

Comment: Where all the notes are displayed? In a grid or in a listbox?

Comment: Notes are displayed in a Panel and every note is inside a FlowLayout Panel.

Comment: @DigambarMalla I thing you are looking for something like this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6646/In-place-editing-of-ListView-subitems

Comment: @Anirugu the link shows something like inplace editing but my requirement is different...

Comment: @DigambarMalla You means you want to change it to textbox only when you click ?

Comment: @Anirugu there will be other textboxes and when we click on the noteId or   NoteType, notedetails will be loaded in respective textboxes.

Comment: what will happen when user fill too long text is pretty small textbox. What about simply add a textbox and hide the data and when user done remove the textbox and show the data.

Comment: @Anirugu, that's not the concern !!!

Comment: Surely you can find a way to solve the problem, for example when you are putting controls in the flow layout panel and panels, you can set tag of parents (or even tag of editing controls)  to node id and then use it to load data from list. But I this is not a common windows forms solution and you can simply use data binding to a list instead of such awkward solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well upon the given suggestion and analysis I found the solution.

Label objects have a Tag property. We can assign Id value to each type and name label. Then, when we click the label, we can get the note Id from Tag property.

For example, consider as Note with Id, Type and Name as 1, Type1 and Name1. Now, the labels that will show Type1 and Name1 will have Tag property value set as 1. You will need to set this value while you are creating the labels. On click event handler you can get the tag value and show correct Note.

Again thanks everyone for the suggestion :)